# Stack around the variable 'xyz' was corrupted

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I'm trying to get some simple piece of code I found on a website to work in VC++ 2010 on windows vista 64:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
 DWORD dResult;
 BOOL result;
 char oldWallPaper[MAX_PATH];

 result = SystemParametersInfo(SPI_GETDESKWALLPAPER, sizeof(oldWallPaper)-1, oldWallPaper, 0);

 fprintf(stderr, "Current desktop background is %s\n", oldWallPaper);

 return 0;
}
```

it does compile, but when I run it, I always get this error:

```
Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'oldWallPaper' was corrupted.
```

I'm not sure what is going wrong, but I noticed, that the value of oldWallPaper looks something like "C\0:\0\0U\0s\0e\0r\0s[...]" -- I'm wondering where all the \0s come from.

- A friend of mine compiled it on windows xp 32 (also VC++ 2010) and is able to run it without problems

any clues/hints/opinions?

thanks

Comment: You should not use `sizeof` on an array, it will _not_ work on an array that you've `malloc` 'd.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The doc isn't very clear. The returned string is a WCHAR, two bytes per character not one, so you need to allocate twice as much space otherwise you get a buffer overrun. Try:

```
BOOL result; 
WCHAR oldWallPaper[(MAX_PATH + 1)]; 

result = SystemParametersInfo(SPI_GETDESKWALLPAPER,
_tcslen(oldWallPaper), oldWallPaper, 0);
```

See also:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724947(VS.85).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235631(VS.80).aspx (string conversion)

Comment: This is the correct answer.

Also, this is C++, not C. std::wcerr << L"Current desktop background is " << oldWallPaper;

Comment: I guess &oldWallPaper should be oldWallPaper

Comment: Could you clarify `&` in `&oldWallPaper`?

Comment: Shouldn't the second argument be (`_tcslen(oldWallPaper)`?  `SystemParametersInfo(SPI_GETDESKTOPWALLPAPER)` requires `uiParam` to be the buffer size *in characters*, not in bytes.  `sizeof(oldWallPaper)` breaks when compiling for Unicode.

Answer (score 3):

Every Windows function has 2 versions:

```
SystemParametersInfoA()   // Ascii
SystemParametersInfoW()   // Unicode
```

The version ending in `W` is the `wide character type` (ie Unicode) version of the function.  All the \0's you are seeing are because every character you're getting back is in Unicode - 16 bytes per character - the second byte happens to be 0.  So you need to store the result in a `wchar_t` array, and use `wprintf` instead of `printf`

```
wchar_t oldWallPaper[MAX_PATH];
result = SystemParametersInfo(SPI_GETDESKWALLPAPER, MAX_PATH-1, oldWallPaper, 0);
wprintf( L"Current desktop background is %s\n", oldWallPaper );
```

So you can use the `A` version `SystemParametersInfoA()` if you are hell-bent on not using Unicode.  For the record you should always try to use Unicode, however.

Usually `SystemParametersInfo()` is a macro that evaluates to the `W` version, if UNICODE is defined on your system.