# C++ Stack around the variable was corrupted

Tags: c++, xml, com, stack

I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11749983/stack-around-the-variable-input-was-corrupted) error and I see [its](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13467583/c-stack-around-a-variable-is-corrupted) rather [popular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2828387/stack-around-the-variable-xyz-was-corrupted)

This issue is rather confusing. I am trying to figure out which variable isn't returned right. This issue was discovered while porting a VC6 project to VS 2012. What happens here is that a record set is taken from the DB and turned in to an XML.

```
CGenAction GenAct(lUserId, O_ALARM, A_GET_TREE, ppALResult)
{
    try
    {
        if (GenAct.BeginAction())
        {
            checkuserPremission(info);

            Result Res;
            Dynaset DynaSet;

            if (type.GetRecordSet(UserId, DynaSet, Res)) {
                turnToXml(DynaSet,Res.m_bstrXMLString);
            }

            returnToUI(Res);
        }
    }
}
```

Before I knew this type of bug I tried placing `Res` and `DynaSet` inside the heap instead of stack by doing something like this:

```
static Result * ResPtr = NULL;

if(ResPtr != NULL)
{
    delete ResPtr;           
}

ResPtr = new Result();
```

This did not help out the issue. The stack around the following variables are corrupted: `Res`, `DynaSet` I will try and narrow it down further and will update the question soon.

Comment: I don't see anything that can cause stack corruption in this code, can you narrow it down and post that code?

Comment: stack around _which_ variable? there are many in your code so it is hard to tell without seeing the code of those classes. Besides, what are these `start/end macro` comments? is this a part of some macro? ` is rather confusing trying to figure out which variable isn't returned right` - error spells exactly which variable is corrupted, can you show the full error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a *very* reliable diagnostic, VC6 didn't have it.  The odds for a false warning are zero.  Do beware that this problem may well have existed in your codebase before you ported.  The bug it warns about is a very serious one and is normally extremely difficult to diagnose without help.  It however doesn't have to be a fatal problem, it can lurk inside code for a long time.  Only to suddenly pop out and wreak havoc with a very innocent looking code change.  Just rebuilding your program with Release build settings can be enough, making diagnosing the problem extra difficult.

Your code snippet is far too opaque to suggest a reason, the undocumented functions may well cause it.  I'll just describe the way the diagnostic works so you'll have a shot at debugging it.

The /RTC debugging option causes the compiler to allocate local variables in the stack frame so they have a space between them.  And it generates a table that identifies those spaces.  At function entry, those spaces are filled with the value 0xcc.  At function exit, it runs a debugging function that walks the table and checks if those spaces still contain 0xcc.  If not, you've got a very reliable indication that code is writing to stack frame locations it should never touch.  A stack buffer overflow is one possibility, there are others.

The way to debug it is to use the Debug + Windows + Memory + Memory 1 window.  Set a breakpoint at the first statement in the function.  When it hits, put EBP in the address box and hit page up (beware that the stack grows down).  You are now looking at the bytes in the stack frame, switching to 4-byte view is usually best.  Try to match the local variables with the values you see.  You should also see the 0xcc values that fill the spaces between variables.  Now start stepping, using the debugger's StepOver command.  Changed values in the stack frame are colored in red.  Try to find the one that is red and contained 0xcc before.

You now have the address of a byte that got whacked.  Restart and use a data breakpoint to get the debugger to stop at the statement that whacked that byte.